# what are best references to learn ExtJS 3.4?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I need to learn ExtJS 3.4 ( pretty older version) and could you please give me some document links. I searched in Google but I am getting most of the links to 4.0 version and above.

If any one having PDFs please share it with me.

Thanks

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention the 3.4 version I assume you work with AEM which is built upon the ExtJS 3.4 version.

Check out this [AEM ExtJS tutorial](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/widgets.html) which is pretty old but quite useful.

Comment: I guess it is not AEM ExtJS. Ext JS 3 version is described here - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/extjs/extjs_overview.htm

Comment: I guess Sencha doc is best to use. You can keep trying to make use of Sencha Doc. And ya @ManojKumar tutorialpoints also introduce ExtJS. That's bit cool to learn.